# Input Stream Invalid read/write of size 1

Tags: c++

i've been absolutely lost on this topic. I wrote my own String class and tried running it in valgrind to see of it really works. Valgrind tells me that i got a lot of invalid read's and write's.

Basically what im trying to do is feed it a String Value and read it's contents later on. For this i defined following Header file.

```
#ifndef STRING_H_INCLUDED
#define STRING_H_INCLUDED
#include<iostream>
#include<istream>
#include<ostream>
class string{
public:
    string(char* = nullptr);
    ~string();
    string(const string&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,string&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,string&);
    bool operator<(const string&);
    bool operator==(const string&);
    void setContent(char*);
    char* getContent() const;
private:
    unsigned getSize() const;
    void copyStr(char*,char*);
    unsigned getCharl(const char*)const;
    string& operator=(const string&);
    char* s = nullptr;
};


#endif // STRING_H_INCLUDED
```

The CPP for the Header looks like the following.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ostream>
#include "string.h"

string::string(char* i){
        if(i == nullptr){
            s = new char[1];
            s[0] = '\0';
        }else{
            s = new char[getCharl(i)+1];
            copyStr(s,i);
        }
    }
    string::~string(){
        if(s != nullptr){
            delete s;
        }
    }

    unsigned string::getCharl(const char* i) const{
        const char* ende = i;
        for(; *ende != '\0';++ende)
            ;
        return ende-i;
    }

    void string::copyStr(char* s,char* i){
        unsigned  index    = 0;
        s = new char[getCharl(i)+1];
        while (i[index] != '\0'){
            s[index] = i[index];
            index++;
        }
        s[index] = '\0';
    }

    bool string::operator<(const string& s1){
        if(getSize()<s1.getSize()){
            return true;
        }else if(getSize()>s1.getSize()){
            return false;
        }else{
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < s1.getSize();++i){
                if(getContent()[i] != s1.getContent()[i]){
                    if(getContent()[i]<s1.getContent()[i]){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    string::string(const string& x){
        delete s;
        s = new char[x.getSize()];
        char* tmp = x.getContent();
        unsigned index = 0;
        while (tmp[index] != '\0'){
            this->s[index] = x.s[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
    char* string::getContent() const{
        return s;
    }

    void string::setContent(char* v){
        s = v;
    }

    string& string::operator=(const string& x){
        if(this == &x)
            return *this;
        if(&x != this){
            delete getContent();
            setContent(nullptr);
            setContent(new char[x.getSize()]);

        }
        copyStr(getContent(),x.getContent());
        return *this;
    }

    bool string::operator==(const string& l){
        if(getSize() == l.getSize()){
            unsigned length = getSize();
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < length;++i){
                if(getContent()[i] != l.getContent()[i])
                    return false;
                }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, string& arg){
        return is >> arg.s;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, string& arg){
        return os << arg.getContent();
    }
    unsigned string::getSize() const{
        unsigned length = 0;
        while(s[length]){
            ++length;
        }
        ++length;
        return length;
    }
```

Basically i would be pretty happy to know why i get an error in my operator>> where i try to write a char* Array to my char* s.

And i would like to know why i get an error in my function getSize() in the while-loop. (Error appears at s[length]).

Maybe someone is so kind to explain me the reasons.

Cheers!

Edit:

Modified the program now to look like the following implementing the comments.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ostream>
#include "string.h"

string::string(char* i){
        if(i == nullptr){
            s = new char[1];
            s[0] = '\0';
        }else{
            s = new char[getCharl(i)+1];
            copyStr(i);
        }
    }
    string::~string(){
        if(s != nullptr){
            delete[] s;
        }
    }

    unsigned string::getCharl(const char* i) const{
        const char* ende = i;
        for(; *ende != '\0';++ende)
            ;
        return ende-i;
    }

    void string::copyStr(char* i){
        unsigned  index    = 0;
        delete[] s;
        char* tmp = new char[getCharl(i)+1];
        while (i[index] != '\0'){
            tmp[index] = i[index];
            index++;
        }
        tmp[index] = '\0';
        s = tmp;
    }

    bool string::operator<(const string& s1){
        if(getSize()<s1.getSize()){
            return true;
        }else if(getSize()>s1.getSize()){
            return false;
        }else{
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < s1.getSize();++i){
                if(getContent()[i] != s1.getContent()[i]){
                    if(getContent()[i]<s1.getContent()[i]){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    string::string(const string& x){
        copyStr(x.getContent());
    }
    char* string::getContent() const{
        return s;
    }

    void string::setContent(char* v){
        s = v;
    }

    string& string::operator=(const string& x){
        if(this == &x)
            return *this;
        if(&x != this){
            delete[] getContent();
            setContent(nullptr);
            setContent(new char[x.getSize()]);

        }
        copyStr(x.getContent());
        return *this;
    }

    bool string::operator==(const string& l){
        if(getSize() == l.getSize()){
            unsigned length = getSize();
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < length;++i){
                if(getContent()[i] != l.getContent()[i])
                    return false;
                }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, string& arg){
        is >> arg.s;
        return is;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, string& arg){
        return os << arg.getContent();
    }
    unsigned string::getSize() const{
        unsigned length = 0;
        while(getContent()[length]){
            ++length;
        }
        ++length;
        return length;
    }
```

Still the problem with the operator>> exists and also now im getting errors in getCharl in the for loop  and copyStr im the while loop. (invalid read)

If someone would be so kind and explain to me why.

Comment: `delete s` exhibits undefined behavior. Should be `delete[] s`, as `s` was allocated with an array form of `new`.

Comment: `copyStr` allocates a new `char` buffer, copies data into it, and then leaks it. The buffer pointed to by the member variable `this->s` remains unchanged.

Comment: Copy constructor `string(const string& x)` fails to allocate space for the terminating NUL character, and in fact doesn't terminate the buffer that `s` points to. Whereas `operator<<` expects `s` to be NUL-terminated.

Comment: What size is the buffer that `arg.s` points to at the time `is >> arg.s` is executed? Are you sure it's large enough to fit the input? Chances are high you have a buffer overrun there; the code certainly makes no attempts to prevent it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how to prevent the buffer overrun? Could you give me an example? And how to fix that this->s gets changed ?

Comment: In `void string::copyStr(char* s,char* i)` `char *s` creates a pointer that is local to the function. It isn't the same as the private member `s` (but if you enable **warnings** that will be made clear). Remove the parameter and simply use a `char *tmp` to allocate and copy to. If the allocation succeeds, `delete[] s` and set `s = tmp;`